# What is the correct way to work with dates in Tarantool?

Tags: tarantool

There are several ways to get time in `Tarantool`:

- Using the `clock` module
- Using `fiber.time` function
- Using `os.date`

But what is the correct way to work with dates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the first, there are several routines for Unix epoch:

1. `os.time()` — classic [Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) time function. Kinda slow and not very efficient. Not recommended to use inside tarantool for getting current epoch, but of course will work. May be used for getting epoch of arbitrary date (within local timezone). ex:

```lua
os.time({ year = 2020, month = 6, day = 4 })
```

will produce `1591261200`, which is 12:00:00 in my GMT+3 timezone

2. `clock.time()` (and `clock.time64()`) — High resolution timer, almost raw binding to `clock_gettime`. More information may be taken from [doc](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/clock/)
3. `fiber.time()` (and also `fiber.time64()`) — Cached version of clock.time. Updated every event loop iteration. Recommended for use if absolute precision of clock is not required.

For converting epoch into different formats and timezones there are variants:

1. `os.date("<format>" [, epoch  ])` — Convert epoch into local timezone.
2. `os.date("!<format>" [, epoch  ])` (note `!` prefix) — Convert epoch into GMT timezone.
3. For getting components of a date as a table we may use `os.date('*t')` for local and `os.date('!*t')` for UTC
4. `icu-date` may be considered it you need to work with different timezones and/or formats.

For example, if you need UTC time, it's ok to use cached `fiber.time` with `os.date`:

```lua
local fiber = require 'fiber'
os.date("!%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", fiber.time())
```

will return something like `2020-06-04T11:48:54Z` independently on timezone

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your task.

If it's important for you to manipulate with timezones/formats etc.
I suggest to use icu-data library (https://github.com/tarantool/icu-date)